# Scroll up and down to hide and show view with delegate functions of UIscrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have implemented the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` to hide the view when users scroll down and once scroll up the view will show immediately. But problem is by using the code below, when user scroll up, the view appear but will hide again when user fingers leave the screen. Is there any better solution for creating the action to show and hide the view I need? Thanks all

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if scrollView == searchCollection{
            if targetContentOffset.pointee.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
                // it's going up
                headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 110
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            } else {
                // it's going down
                headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            }

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there as per my opinion use pangesture

```
var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

//inSide viewDidLoad()
panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureAction(_:)))
self.yourScrollview.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

//Create function like below
    @objc func panGestureAction(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        guard gestureRecognizer.view != nil else {return}

        let fileView = gestureRecognizer.view!
        let directionVelocity = gestureRecognizer.velocity(in: myView)
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {

        case .began :

        break
        case .changed:

            if directionVelocity.x > 0 {

                print("swipe right")
            }

            if directionVelocity.x < 0 {

                print("swipe left")
            }

            if directionVelocity.y > 0 {

                print("swipe down")
            }

            if directionVelocity.y < 0 {

               print("swipe up")

            }
        break

    case .ended :

        print("end")

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you,
Thank you.

Comment: bro I tried your code, my uicollectionview become non scrollable, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @klkl can you add your gesture in collection view like "self.collectionview.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)"

Comment: Ya I tried that way but the uicollectionview still non scrollable

Comment: @klkl please check hierarchy UIViews in storyboard.

Comment: @klkl can you set user interaction on of collectionView?Please confirm if it's set false  then then :-"self.parentView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it is working at my end.

```
@interface ViewController (){

    __weak IBOutlet UIView *view3;
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *view2;
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *view1;

    BOOL isshowing;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - UIView Controller Life Cycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    isshowing = YES;

}
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; {

        CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        CGFloat viewOffset = view1.frame.size.height + view1.frame.origin.y;

        if (viewOffset > offset) {

            if (isshowing == NO) {
                view1.hidden = NO;
                view1.alpha = 0;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                    view1.alpha = 1;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
            }
            isshowing = YES;



            NSLog(@"View 1 show");
        }
        if (viewOffset < offset) {
            if (isshowing == YES) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                    view1.alpha = 0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    view1.hidden = YES;
                }];
            }


            isshowing = NO;

            NSLog(@"View 1 Hide");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Question's and tagged language is swift not objective-c

Comment: bro i try your code, the view failed to display when the users scroll up, the view only appear if the scrollview scroll to the top.

Comment: You have to do the sum of height and y axis in order to check again scroll view offset. Give me your code , let me check.

Comment: Like it did it CGFloat viewOffset = view1.frame.size.height + view1.frame.origin.y;

Answer (score 0):

My Swift solution

```
var isShowing: Bool = true
var animationDuration: CGFloat {
    0.3
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let viewOffset = (self.frame.size.height / 2) + self.frame.origin.y
    if viewOffset < offset, !self.isShowing {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration) {
            self.alpha = 1
        }
        self.isShowing = true
    } else if viewOffset > offset, self.isShowing {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.animationDuration, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            self.isHidden = true
        })
        self.isShowing = false
    }
}
```